# Should we add the hackintosh tag as synonym for mac?

Tags: discussion

While reviewing https://askubuntu.com/questions/551913/i-need-to-remount-hackintosh-disk-r-w I was wondering whether we should create a [hackintosh](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/hackintosh) as synonym for [mac](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mac). There are quite a number of questions with "hackintosh" in their title or text. Since I don't have enough points yet to have the privilege of creating a synonym myself I'm asking it here.

Comment: [apple.se] doesn't have that tag. Should we?

Comment: Ask Different should have that tag.

Comment: @Whaaaaaat nope. Things that are [off-topic on AD](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) include: "*Installing or using Apple operating systems on non-Apple hardware (and most other explicitly unlicensed use of product)*" (i.e., Hackintosh)..

Comment: @muru Hackintosh.SE anyone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag really doesn't have anything to do with Ubuntu.

Scenarios:

- User is using it. has problem with it - not about ubuntu.
- User is dual booting. just like any other dual boot, except with for the problems about it, which are not about ubuntu.

  - Client is it, virtual machine is Ubuntu, treat just like mac.
  - Using a virtual machine with it, likely nothing to do with Ubuntu.

Plus since the *Legal* or at least *Licensing agreement* status of such a use is not allowed or at best "murky" **IANAL** (I Am Not A Lawyer) Such questions are not a good fit for this site anyway.

Comment: I see my mistake now: I thought a hackintosh was a Mac running another (e.g. Ubuntu Linux) OS. It turns out to be the reverse: running Mac OS X on non-Apple hardware. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

There are no others tagged hackintosh. It looks like the hackintosh tag doesn't even exist. Why create one just to synonymize it? If it appears naturally, certainly synonymize it, but until it does appear...

Comment: The reason why I asked in the first place was because I was about to create the `hackintosh` tag. Before doing that I looked around and found several posts that looked like they could benefit from such a tag. As far as I understand, tags are there to help identify questions that are about a similar subject. While I was doing this 'research' I ran into the `mac` tag, which made me wonder if `hackintosh` was indeed to be considered a synonym.